# Number of applications between two sets

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

In a certain exercise I am asked to find the number of applications (not neccesarily bijective) such that for $f: X \rightarrow X, f(k) \not= k$, where $X = \{1\dots n\}$. This is my approach. It seems so simple that I think I must be wrong somewhere:

For each $i \in X$, one can send $i$ to as much as $n-1$ elements (everyone excepting $i$ itself). Therefore, there are $(n-1)^n$ of these applications. Am I right?

Comment: Of course you are right. The problem is only interesting for bijections.

Comment: As far as I am concerned, for bijections the problem involves something whose name I don't know in English. In Spanish we call it "desbarajustes". In that case, it is more complex

Comment: [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement)

Comment: By the way, if I was asked about bijections, why it wouldn't be just $(n-1)$ possibilities for the first element, $(n-2)$ for the second one, $(n-k)$ possibilities for the $k$ element, and therefore that product?

Comment: $n-k$ possibilities for the $k^{th}$ element, so $0$ for the $n^{th}$ elemengt??

Comment: Actually, $n-1$ possibilities for the first element, but then either $n-1$ or $n-2$ possibilities for the second element, depending on whether the first element was sent to the second element or elsewhere.

Comment: Perfect, that makes sense, since I was wondering why it wouldn't be an easier formula too